# C# LINQ Target needs to be static

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

In the following code, why is it necessary for the array (arr) to be static ?

If I remove static, then it is no more visible for using in the LINQ query.

```
class A
{
     static int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
     IEnumerable<int> result = from i in arr where i < 10 select i;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access other class instance variables if you directly initialize variables using a variable initializer - you could move the code to the constructor instead:

```
class A
{
     int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
     IEnumerable<int> result;

     public A()
     {
         result = from i in arr where i < 10 select i;
     }
}
```

From the C# spec, **10.5.5.2 Instance field initialization**:

> A variable initializer for an instance
>   field cannot reference the instance
>   being created. Thus, it is a
>   compile-time error to reference this
>   in a variable initializer, as it is a
>   compile-time error for a variable
>   initializer to reference any instance
>   member through a simple-name.

This makes sense, since variable initializers are executed before the base class constructor, hence the class instance has not been fully "constructed" yet.

Comment: What is the order of construction of static members?

Comment: It's weird that when you changed them both to static it works.

Comment: While allocation of memory, is there any particular order that is followed? From this discussion I infer that static data is allocated first and is separate from instances, which is why using static in this case works, not using static will break the rule as mentioned by @BrokenGlass

Comment: @Amit: static variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear when the *type* is initialized, which is before any instance of the type is constructed or any static member of the type has been accessed

Comment: @BrokenGlass "static variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear" try making both of his fields static and then switching their order, it still compiles.

Comment: @Yuriy: If you declare `result` first it **compiles** yes, but it will throw a `TypeInitializationException` on first access - try it out. This is because `arr` will still have its default value of `null`

Comment: @BrokenGlass I see what you're saying. My mistake.